# undo or revert git am --resolved

Tags: git, git-am, git-apply

I was manually applying the patch and after I was done I did the following

```
git add . 
git am --resolved
```

I had overlooked the part that the rej file was also present and was untracked but `git add .` added all the files to the staging area as expected and on `git am --resolved` I ended up committing my rej file which had the patch diffs .

I did a `git reset --soft HEAD^` so I could revert the commit and just commit the file modified by the patch .

But the issue now is that commit message and author would not be extracted from the patch file anymore since I did a git commit.

**How do I undo a git resolved so I could remove the rej file and resolve again so the commit messages and author are intact?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like there is only one commit in the patch.

The easiest way **in this case** (just the one commit) is to `git reset` *back* to the incorrect commit, then remove the extra file (`git rm ...`) and use `git commit --amend`.  The `--amend` option tells `git commit` to re-use the existing message and author, and make a new commit from the current index, shoving the old commit aside.

If there are multiple commits, all containing the `.rej` file, you will need to use [Leon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40270059/1256452) or something similar (e.g., a longer manual rebase).  You may wish to limit the set of commits copied by `git filter-branch` since filtering copies every such commit, which is very slow.

To reset back to the incorrect commit, use `git reset --soft HEAD@{1}` as Leon said.

Answer (score 4):

You could simply have done

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm rejfile' HEAD^..
```

Now you must return to the wrongly committed state with

```
git reset --soft HEAD@{1}
```

and then run the `git filter-branch` command from above.